regexp multiple lines grep
I am looking for a correct regexp to return the first match and the new line.
Let's say the logfile is like:
Warning-[ABC] blablabla$
 
/path1/path2/path3/file

The dollar at the end of the first line is shown if I do "cat -e logfile", so no \n character.
I tried this without any luck:
grep -E '^Warning-\[ABC\] blablabla(\$)*^/path1.*' logfile

Could I get some help please?
Thanks

It's unclear what exactly is the input and what output you expect. Note that cat -e uses $ to show an end of line.

Use grep with -P option (Perl):

    grep -P '^Warning-\[ABC\] blablabla(\$)\s+/path1.*' logfile


It seems you haven't a dollar sign in your file. Just remove it from the regex. It becomes:
grep -P '^Warning-\[ABC\] blablabla\s+/path1.*' logfile


It doesn't work, but if I add * after ($) it works on regex101.com
https://regex101.com/r/hQiMmk/1

@Ste3191: Do you have a $ sign in your file? You didn't put one in your regex101 example. If you haven't, just remove (\$) from the regex.

The $ sign is present only from cat -e logfile, in a normal editor I see two different lines, I tried without ($) but it doesn't work :(

It works if I do grep -Pz
